# Tabulate part of text file written by shell

Tags: shell

I have a shell script that is writing(echoing) the output on an array to a file. The file is in the following format

```
The tansaction detials for today are 35 

    Please check the 5 biggest transactions below   

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Client Name,Account Number,Amount,Tran Time
Michael Press,20484,602117,11.41.02
Adam West,164121,50152,11.41.06
John Smith,15113,411700,11.41.07
Leo Anderson,2115116,350056,11.41.07
Wayne Clark,451987,296503,11.41.08
```

And i have multiple such line.

How do i tabulate the names after ---?
I tried using spaces while echoing the array elements. Also tried tabs. I tried using `column -t -s` options. But the text above the --- is interfering with the desired output.

The desired output is

```
The tansaction detials for today are 35 

    Please check the 5 biggest transactions below   

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Client Name   Account Number   Amount  Tran Time
Michael Press 20484            602117  11.41.02
Adam West     164121           50152   11.41.06
John Smith    15113            411700  11.41.07
Leo Anderson  2115116          350056  11.41.07
Wayne Clark   451987           296503  11.41.08
```

The printing to a file is a part of a bigger script. So, i am looking for a simple solution to plug into this script. 
Here's the snippet from that script where i am echoing to the file.

```
echo "The tansaction detials for today are 35 " >> log.txt
echo "" >> log.txt
echo "  Please check the 5 biggest transactios below   " >> log.txt
echo "" >> log.txt
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> log.txt
echo "" >> log.txt
echo "" >> log.txt
echo "Client Name,Account Number,Amount,Tran Time" >> log.txt
array=( `output from a different script` )
x=1
for i in ${array[@]}
do

        #echo "Array $x - $i"
        Clientname=$(echo $i | cut -f1 -d',')
        accountno=$(echo $i | cut -f2 -d',')
        amount=$(echo $i | cut -f3 -d',')
        trantime=$(echo $i | cut -f4 -d',')

echo "$Clientname,$accountno,$amount,$trantime" >> log.txt
(( x=$x+1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, in order to produce the output format of:

```
Client Name   Account Number   Amount  Tran Time
Michael Press 20484            602117  11.41.02
Adam West     164121           50152   11.41.06
John Smith    15113            411700  11.41.07
Leo Anderson  2115116          350056  11.41.07
Wayne Clark   451987           296503  11.41.08
```

You should use the output *formatting* provided by `printf` instead of `echo`. For example, for the headings, you can use:

```
printf "Client Name   Account Number   Amount  Tran Time\n" >> log.txt
```

instead of:

```
echo "Client Name,Account Number,Amount,Tran Time" >> log.txt
```

For writing the five largest amounts and details, you could use:

```
printf "%-14s%-17s%8s%s\n" "$Clientname" "$accountno" "$amount" "$trantime" >> log.txt
```

instead of:

```
echo "$Clientname,$accountno,$amount,$trantime" >> log.txt
```

If that isn't what you are needing, just drop a comment and let me know and I'm happy to help further.

(you may have to tweak the *field widths* a bit, I just did a rough count)

---

**True Tabular Output Requires Measuring Each Field**

If you want to insure that your data is always in tabular form, you need to measure each field width (including the heading) and then take the max of either the field width (or heading) to set the field width for your output. Below is an example of how that can be done (using your simulated *other program input*):

```
#!/bin/bash

ofn="log.txt"   # set output filename

# declare variables as array and integer types
declare -a line_arr hdg name acct amt trn tmp
declare -i nmx=0 acmx=0 ammx=0 tmx=0

# set heading array (so you can measure lengths)
hdg=( "Client Name"
      "Account Number"
      "Ammount"
      "Tran Time" )

## set the initial max based on headings
nmx="${#hdg[0]}"    # max name width
acmx="${#hdg[1]}"   # max account width
ammx="${#hdg[2]}"   # max ammount width
tmx="${#hdg[3]}"    # max tran width

{ IFS=$'\n'         # your array=( `output from a different script` )
line_arr=($(
cat << EOF
Michael Press,20484,602117,11.41.02
Adam West,164121,50152,11.41.06
John Smith,15113,411700,11.41.07
Leo Anderson,2115116,350056,11.41.07
Wayne Clark,451987,296503,11.41.08
EOF
)
)
}

# write heading to file
cat << EOF > "$ofn"
The tansaction detials for today are 35

    Please check the 5 biggest transactions below

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


EOF

# read line array into tmp, compare to max field widths
{ IFS=$','
for i in "${line_arr[@]}"; do
    tmp=( $(printf "%s" "$i") )
    ((${#tmp[0]} > nmx )) && nmx=${#tmp[0]}
    ((${#tmp[1]} > acmx )) && acmx=${#tmp[1]}
    ((${#tmp[2]} > ammx )) && ammx=${#tmp[2]}
    ((${#tmp[3]} > tmx )) && tmx=${#tmp[3]}
    name+=( "${tmp[0]}" )   # fill name array
    acct+=( "${tmp[1]}" )   # fill account num array
    amt+=( "${tmp[2]}" )    # fill amount array
    trn+=( "${tmp[3]}" )    # fill tran array
done
}

printf "%-*s  %-*s  %-*s  %s\n" "$nmx" "${hdg[0]}" "$acmx" "${hdg[1]}" \
"$ammx" "${hdg[2]}" "${hdg[3]}" >> "$ofn"
for ((i = 0; i < ${#name[@]}; i++)); do
    printf "%-*s  %-*s  %-*s  %s\n" "$nmx" "${name[i]}" "$acmx" "${acct[i]}" \
"$ammx" "${amt[i]}" "${trn[i]}" >> "$ofn"
done
```

(you can remove the extra `space` between each field in the final two `printf` statements if you only want a single `space` between them -- looked better with 2 to me)

**Output to log.txt**

```
$ cat log.txt
The tansaction detials for today are 35

    Please check the 5 biggest transactions below

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Client Name    Account Number  Ammount  Tran Time
Michael Press  20484           602117   11.41.02
Adam West      164121          50152    11.41.06
John Smith     15113           411700   11.41.07
Leo Anderson   2115116         350056   11.41.07
Wayne Clark    451987          296503   11.41.08
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: this isn't working, since there are some lines in the array that are longer and some shorter. So, just seperating them with spaces is not exatcly tabulating it.

Comment: That's why I say you may need to adjust the *field width* modifiers to whatever the longest string for that field is. You can supply the *field width* as an argument to each `printf` *conversion specifier* (e.g. `%*s` and you pass `printf "%*s..." "$width" "$field"` (in that order) to accommodate any length field. It is a very flexible way to handle tabular output. You know you can get the maximum width of each of the fields with `${#varname}` , e.g. `${#Clientname}`

Comment: I tried with different widths for the fields but still the output isn't pretty. i mean i am able to seperate the fields but they still not in a straight line. The above is just a sample. I have a lot more such lines with varied lengths.

Comment: I see there is no issue with the printf options. The text file being output is perfect. the issue is happening when i mail this text file. I am simply doing `/bin/mail/ -s "Subject" email@email.com < log.txt`. This messing up the format.

Comment: Hmm..., that certainly shouldn't be happening *unless* you used a `tab` character (e.g. `'\t'`) in some of the other lines. (or there are some other stray control characters that are somehow getting written to `log.txt`). I don't know which `mail` program you are using (I recommend `nails`, it is the continuation of the `heirloom-mailx` code). The problem with `tabs` is they are handled as many different ways as there are mail programs to handle them. See if you can get `log.txt` to contain nothing but `spaces` and `text` and see if the problem disappears.

Comment: Nope. There were some tabs, i removed them. But still nothing. I am using /bin/mail. I tried with sendmail too. still no luck

Comment: Show me how `array=( \`output from a different script\` )` is generated. I'm still thinking there are stray characters being captured somewhere in your process. What I will do is re-write your script to eliminate `echo` completely, provide proper `newline` control through `printf` and eliminate all calls to `cut` replacing with *parameter expansion w/substring removal or replacement*. There is nothing magic about tabular formatting, but if you are dealing with some strange character issue, you can pull your hair out. Also show `output from a different script | hexdump -C`. What OS?

Comment: I am getting the output from a script into an array and slitting it up with the code in the original question. This is the output in the array in each seperate line. 
    `Michael Press,20484,602117,11.41.02
     
      Adam West,164121,50152,11.41.06
     
     John Smith,15113,411700,11.41.07
     
      Leo Anderson,2115116,350056,11.41.07
     
      Wayne Clark,451987,296503,11.41.08`

I don't see anything special characters in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121270/discussion-between-user3164754-and-david-c-rankin).

Comment: I don't either, give me a bit to play with this output and your script and I'll post an edit to my answer.

Comment: don't know if you saw my chat message. We are using RHEL6.I also posted the hexdump in the chat message.

Comment: I saw it, but I was working on an appeal today and didn't have a lot of time. Take a look at the update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand everythings =P

but to answer this question :

> How do i tabulate the names after ---?

```
echo -e "Example1\tExample2"
```

-e means : enable interpretation of backslash escapes

So for your output, I suggest :

```
echo -e "$Clientname\t$accountno\t$amount\t$trantime" >> log.txt
```

**Edit :** If you need more space, you can double,triple,... it

```
echo -e "Example1\t\tExample2"
```

Comment: Is it helpful to you ?